# xcode #import autocomplete stopped working after a tidy up

Tags: xcode

I've moved a load of files from my project into sub folders to tidy everything up.
I've told xcode where all the files are now located and my project works fine like it used to.
The only problem i'm now facing, is when I #import a header, xcode no longer autocompletes the filename for me. It's become quite annoying.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks

EDIT---
It seems it CAN autocomplete for files that are stored in the same folder as the file i'm working on.
Should it be able to autocomplete for files a branch above or sidewards?

Comment: Did you tried cleaning the project / deleting derived data?

Comment: Yes. I deleted Derived Data although Organizer doesn't even show any derived data for my project (it does for others).